# How to upload phonegap build app in google playstore?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-build

Whenever I am trying to upload app which has formed by phonegap build method (Which have only config.xml and index.html file) getting an error

> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.
>
> You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more about signing.

My search found the solution that to make `debuggable="false"` in `androidmanifest.xml`. But the thing is that there is no such file in the case of phonegap build method. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The solution you found is wrong. This is how you do it.

In the future, read the [official documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans%28en%29).

If you are confused, ask question at the official [Phonegap Build forum](https://forums.adobe.com/community/phonegap/build) or the [Nitobi forum](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi).

The instructions you need for signing are at this link: *[Android Signing](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-android.md.html#Android%20Signing) for Google Play*

The final step is, which is not documented very well, is here:
[Builing a release version for build.phonegap.com](https://unbot.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/builing-a-release-version-for-build-phonegap-com/)